# Generate a simple table with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I dont understand why but I'm getting the wrong body structure. You can see on the image that I get a `<tr></tr>` and I dont have that on javascript.

I just want a table with 3 columns and up to 10 rows.

What's happening?

[My generated html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jmgn.png)

JavaScript

```
  $('#selectMRPC').change(function () {
    //fetch data
    var mrpc = $(this).find('option:selected').data('mrpc');

    $('#paramBody').empty();
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        var field = mrpc["field" + i];
        if (field !== undefined) {
            var parsedField = field.split('_');
            var value = parsedField[0];
            var type = parsedField[1];

            switch (type) {
                case  "S":
                    type = "text";
                    if (value === '""')
                        value = null;
                    break;
                case "B":
                    type = "checkbox";
                    break;
                case "N":
                    type = "number";
                    value = parseInt(value);
                    break;
                case "D":
                    type = "number";
                    value = parseInt(value);
                    if (value === '""')
                        value = null;
                    break;
            }
            $('#paramBody').append('<tr>');
            $('#paramBody').append('<td>' + i + '</td>');
            $('#paramBody').append('<td>' + type + '</td>');
            $('#paramBody').append('<td><input name="Fields" type="' + type + '">').val(value);
            $('#paramBody').append('</tr>');

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Please post the relevant Markup in the question directly. We can't copy markup from an image and images are not loaded all the time for everyone or are readable on all devices. Please see [**Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) for more issues code in images cause.

Comment: Alright........

Comment: Have you tried building the entire row and storing it in the variable, then appending it to the table instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

store everything in a var then add it to dom :

```
var html = "";

html += '<tr>';
html += '<td>' + i + '</td>';
html += '<td>' + type + '</td>';
html += '<td><input name="Fields" type="' + type + '" value="' + value +'">';
html += '</tr>';

$('#paramBody').append(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

[append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) will create an element from the parameter if the given input is not already a *valid html string*

Make it

```
$('#paramBody').append('<tr><td>' + i + '</td><td>' + type + '</td><td><input name="Fields" type="' + type + '" value="' +value + '"></tr>');
```

Or append them one by one (example below)

```
$( "<tr></tr>" ).append('<td>' + i + '</td>').appendTo( '#paramBody' );
```

Or create a string first

```
  var html = '<tr>';
  html += '<td>' + i + '</td>';
  html += '<td>' + type + '</td>';
  html += '<td><input name="Fields" type="' + type + '" value="' + value + '">';
  html += '</tr>';


 $('#paramBody').append(html );
```

Comment: isn't there a more clean way to make it? I tried to use many appends to make it more clean.

Comment: Using more would append would actually affect the performance. It's better to create the HTML and use append once.

Answer (score 0):

You are appending everything to `#paramBody`, which is incorrect. Consecutively, you need to append/insert data into `<tr>`. So I would recommend, you concatenate everything together instead of appending.

You need to change

```
$('#paramBody').append('<tr>');
            $('#paramBody').append('<td>' + i + '</td>');
            $('#paramBody').append('<td>' + type + '</td>');
            $('#paramBody').append('<td><input name="Fields" type="' + type + '">').val(value);
            $('#paramBody').append('</tr>');
```

to

```
var rowHtml = '<tr>' + '<td>' + i + '</td>' + '<td>' + type + '</td>' + '<td><input name="Fields" type="' + type + '">' + value + '</tr>';
$('#paramBody').append(rowHtml);
```